# Issue with pyRevit forms

Tags: revit-api, revitpythonshell, pyrevit

I am trying to use pyRevit to automate some tasks in Revit, but when I try to run an example code, it shows an error.

Code:

```
from pyrevit import forms
ops = ['option1', 'option2', 'option3', 'option4']
forms.CommandSwitchWindow.show(ops, message='Select Option')
```

Output:

```
Exception : Microsoft.Scripting.ArgumentTypeException: LoadComponent() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.ThrowInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run5[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute4[T0,T1,T2,T3,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
   at IronPython.Compiler.Ast.CallExpression.Invoke2Instruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run6[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5)
   at IronPython.Compiler.PythonCallTargets.OriginalCallTarget5(PythonFunction function, Object arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2, Object arg3, Object arg4)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`8.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run8[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6, T7 arg7)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute7[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.DynamicInstruction`8.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run7[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute6[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.DynamicInstruction`7.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run6[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5)
   at IronPython.Compiler.PythonCallTargets.OriginalCallTarget5(PythonFunction function, Object arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2, Object arg3, Object arg4)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`8.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run6[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute5[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.DynamicInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run7[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6)
   at IronPython.Compiler.PythonCallTargets.OriginalCallTarget6(PythonFunction function, Object arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2, Object arg3, Object arg4, Object arg5)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`9.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run9[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6, T7 arg7, T8 arg8)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute8[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6, T7 arg7)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , CodeContext , Object , Object , Object , Object , Object , Object )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute7[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6)
   at IronPython.Runtime.Types.PythonType.FastTypeSite`5.CallTarget(CallSite site, CodeContext context, Object type, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute7[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.DynamicInstruction`8.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run7[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5, T6 arg6)
   at IronPython.Compiler.PythonCallTargets.OriginalCallTarget6(PythonFunction function, Object arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2, Object arg3, Object arg4, Object arg5)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`9.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run6[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute5[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.DynamicInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run5[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute4[T0,T1,T2,T3,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.DynamicInstruction`5.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run2[T0,T1,TRet](T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.RunWorker(CodeContext ctx)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptSource.Execute(ScriptScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptSource.ExecuteAndWrap(ScriptScope scope, ObjectHandle& exception)
```

Screenshot for reference:
[RevitPythonShell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x86Iy.png)

Tried reinstalling pyRevit and changing its Active Engine, but the issue persists.

Comment: Did you try to install older version of pyrevit? Did you try by type only:
from pyrevit import forms
ops = ['option1', 'option2', 'option3', 'option4'] forms.CommandSwitchWindow(ops, message='Select Option')?

Comment: Yes, I have tried those, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah but did you try install older version of pyrevit?